# Directing user to '/en/' or '/fr/' path upon loading page with React?

Tags: reactjs, routes, localization

I'm wondering how I can direct the user to the correct language path for their location upon loading the page in react?

I know I can detect their locaalized langauge with navigator.language. But then how do I use that to route them to a page immediately?

Comment: Did our answers fix your problem? Please let us now so we can help you out! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could have a functional component as a intro component in your app that will read that location and route to the correct language using the `useHistory` hook like this:

```js
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function HomePage() {
  const history = useHistory();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Use navigator.language here
    history.push("/en"); 
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      Loading...
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can always read more about it in the [React Router docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) and in the [React Hooks docs](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should read https://reactrouter.com/web/api/

`navigator.language` returns the browser's language,
and I assume that it is what you really want

I did it with `basename` that is one of `BrowserRouter` properties

```
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  NavLink,
  Redirect,
  Route,
  Switch
} from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const lang = navigator.language.split("-")[0];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter basename={lang}>
        <Menu />
        <Switch>
          <Redirect exact from="/" to="/home" />
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/home" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
          <Redirect to="/home" />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
export const Menu = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <NavLink to="./home">Home</NavLink>
      <span> / </span>
      <NavLink to="./about">About</NavLink>
    </>
  );
};
export const Home = () => {
  return <h1>Home</h1>;
};
export const About = () => {
  return <h1>About</h1>;
};
```